# React Testing Library - using 'await wait()' after fireEvent

Tags: arrays, reactjs, async-await, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm trying to use Testing Library to check for DOM Elements after a fireEvent.click. I know I need to wait after the fireEvent, but am not sure why simply using await doesn't work? Below is the same test written two ways -- the first one fails, the second passes. I don't understand why the first one fails...am very grateful for any insights!

p.s. -- I know wait is deprecated and waitFor is preferred, however due to some constraints I can not update the version at this time :(

FAILING TEST

```js
// This test fails with the following error and warning:
// Error: Unable to find an element by: [data-test="name_wrapper"]
// Warning: An update to OnlinePaymentModule inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).

  it('this is a failing test...why', async () => {
      const { getByText, getByTestId } = render(<Modal {...props} />);
      const button = getByText('open modal');

      fireEvent.click(button);

        const nameWrapper =  await getByTestId('name_wrapper');
        expect(
          nameWrapper.getElementsByTagName('output')[0].textContent
        ).toBe('Jon Doe');

        const numberWrapper = await getByTestId('number_wrapper');
        expect(
          numberWrapper.getElementsByTagName('output')[0].textContent
        ).toBe('123456');
        
    });
```

PASSING TEST -- Why does this pass but first one fails?

```js
// This test passes with no warnings

  it('this is a passing test...why', async () => {
      const { getByText, getByTestId } = render(<Modal {...props} />);
      const button = getByText('open modal');

      fireEvent.click(button);
      
      await wait(() => {
        const nameWrapper = getByTestId('name_wrapper');
        expect(
          nameWrapper.getElementsByTagName('output')[0].textContent
        ).toBe('Jon Doe');

        const numberWrapper = getByTestId('number_wrapper');
        expect(
          numberWrapper.getElementsByTagName('output')[0].textContent
        ).toBe('123456');
      })  
    });
```

Comment: In first example `getByTestId` does not return a Promise so those awaits are pointless.

Comment: In second example you could do `await wait()` and than continue.

Comment: Can you explain more about doing await wait(), then continue?

Comment: You can read more on https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async, there are some good examples. E.g. what `await waitFor(callback)` does is wait till callback is true and than continues.

Comment: Would it be better to wrap each constant in in await wait() (e.g await wait(() => const nameWrapper = getByTestId('name_wrapper')))...then leave the expect assertions outside of the awaits ...since I really only need to wait for the element to found?

Comment: No, but what you can is first `await waitFor(() => getByTestId(...)); const el = getByTestId(...)`.

Comment: One more good source would be https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous

Answer (score 77):

5 months later I'm coming back to answer my question (I've learned a lot since posting this question lol)....

First of all, since it is 5 months later I want to underscore that it is better to use the `userEvent` library instead of `fireEvent` if possible.

I also would be remiss to not call out that there are a lot of antipatterns in the code ...You should only ever make one assertion in `waitFor`. You should avoid using `getByTestId` in favor of more accessible alternatives.

And finally the reason the first test was failing is that you can not use `wait` with `getBy*`. `getBy` is not async and will not wait. This would have been the better solution:

```
fireEvent.click(button);
const nameWrapper =  await findByTestId('name_wrapper');
```

Then the test would have waited on the `nameWrapper` element to be available.

The second test passed because `getBy` is wrapped in RTL's async utility, `wait` (`wait` is now deprecated in favor of `waitFor`). That is essentially what `findBy` does under the hood -- `findBy` is the async version of `getBy`.

When I posted the question I didn't fully understand that `await` is a Javascript key word (and just syntactical sugar to make code wait on a promise to resolve). `wait` (now `waitFor`) is a utility from RTL that will make execution of the test wait until the callback does not throw an error.

Comment: You do not need `await` with findByTestId, do you?

Comment: @wuarmin you do need `await`. Otherwise, the code on the next line will execute, before the promise has resolved.

Comment: `findByTestId` is not `async`, so `await` has no effect

Comment: I think you mean `getByTestId` is not `async`  so `await` has no effect. `findBy` queries return a promise and must be awaited :)